# Fetching data affer submitting values to Comboboxes and Datetime object of a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to fetch the value from a link, so wrote the code till opening the page

```
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.add_argument("--headless");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   
driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm")
```

After this, need to enter values,

[image]

for example,

```
1. Select Instrument = "Option Types"
2. Select Symbol = "Reliance"
3. Select Year = "2020"
4. Select Expiry = "31-Mar-2016"
5. Select Option Type = "CE"
6. Strike Price = 960
7. For past = 24 Months
8. From Period = "22-Feb-2016"
9. To Expiry = "31-Mar-2016"
```

Then after clicking the get data button, we get a table as shown below

[image]

This all data to be captured in a data frame and need to print all values from Close column one by one. How to enter data in boxes and get this data?

Answer (score 1):

for entering the data, you have dropdown lists and textboxes WebElements. You can insent data into them like in this example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options_from_instrument = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@name = 'dataForm']/div[@class = 'viewdata-content']/select"))
options_from_instrument.select_by_visible_text("Stock Options")

strike_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@name = 'dataForm']/div[@class = 'viewdata-content']/input[@name = 'strikePrice']")
strike_price.send_keys("960")
```

To capture all the data into a dataframe, you can write everything into a file with the corresponding separation between columns. For printing the column close, I think it is enough just to use an integer that checks for the column indexing.

```
with open("data_table.txt", "r") as output:
entries = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class ='tabular-data-historic']//tbody/tr") #tr holds for each entry of the data frame.
for entry in entries:
    if entry.text != "Historical Contract-wise Price Volume Data": #We don't want the header.
        values_of_entry = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("./th")
        col = 0
        for value in values_of_entry:
            output.write(f"{value.text}\t")
            if col == 8:                        # Column Close is in index 8
                print (f"{value.text}\n")
            col+= 1

        output.write("\n")
output.close()
```

Comment: entries = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class ='tabular-data-historic']//tbody/tr") #tr holds for each entry of the data frame. -  This is giving error